# Free up memory from MkMapView for good

Tags: swift, memory, mkmapview, mapkit

Here is the thing, I have a demo app written on swift and my MkMapView takes off from 60mb to 80mb of my free memory(using simulator) so I want to free it up, especially since it completely reloads the map anyway when I click on the "Open map" button again.

So I am overriding a `func viewWillDisappear` and code I am trying to run will be:

```
self.mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Hybrid
self.mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Standard
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = false
self.mapView.delegate = nil
self.mapView.removeFromSuperview()
self.mapView = nil
```

BUT, neither of these makes effect.
With this changes my app hold ~20mb after fresh launch, then I am clicking "Open man" button and memory usage jump up to 170mb(!), after that I could jump back using navBarButton, but memory usage wont drop below ~120 or something like that. Which is sick. I want my memory back!

Comment: Are you optimizing prematurely?  Or do you have a leak?  Does the memory usage grow every time you open this view?  Or once opened, it makes a big jump, but then just stays at this level rather than going down?

Comment: Tools dont show any leaks whatsoever, except some rare tricky swift-related ones, I am pretty sure the MkMapView is eating a memory "by design", I can see how its build up the memory usage when I open the map, so yes, Usage grow every time I open the view, but its consistent, it wont go up higher then 160-170 mb no matter how much times I open-close the view. And yea after I press back it frees up some memory, about 10%-15%, but then when you open map again it rolls back to 100% (which is 160-170mb)

Comment: @AnatoleyKovalev i am facing similar problem.If you solved it then please let me know any solution.thanks

Comment: @Johnny are you testing your app on the simulator? Because it turns out to be ok to eat that much memory in simulator. Try testing on a real device. I am observing 5x+ times different memory consumption between simulator and real device when using mapkit

Comment: Yeah i am testing it on simulator.Ok if that's  not the issue on real device than i am ok..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it is ok for simulator to eat that much memory when showing maps and stuff.

If you are worried about your app memory efficiency, try to get your hands on a real device(before you go crazy), since memory usage between real device and simulator could vary up to 5x times or more.